# Download SQLite file programmatically

Tags: java, android, sqlite

In my android application i'm using SQLite database.
And I need to have an option in the app to download the database file.

Because sometimes I need to view the data there , so the user will download the file and send it to me and i will browse it using SQLite browsers.

Is the doable? if yes how?

```
   String src = "/data/data/myPackage/databases/Mydb.db";
   String dest = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath();

copyFileOrDirectory(src , dest);

 public static void copyFileOrDirectory(String srcDir, String dstDir) {

        try {
            File src = new File(srcDir);
            File dst = new File(dstDir, src.getName());

                copyFile(src, dst);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
        if (!destFile.getParentFile().exists())
            destFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();

        if (!destFile.exists()) {
            destFile.createNewFile();
        }

        FileChannel source = null;
        FileChannel destination = null;

        try {
            source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
            destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
            destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
        } finally {
            if (source != null) {
                source.close();
            }
            if (destination != null) {
                destination.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: it's not related to the question , I'm successfully saving data to the sqlite using SQLiteOpenHelper and this is the path of the db /data/data/myPacakge/databases/myDatabase.db

Comment: The SQLite database is already on the User's device, since they have the application which is using the database. So you just need them to be able to access it so that they can send it to you.

Comment: Ok, so what is your question?

Comment: @just My question is how to get the database file from users. They cannot access the folder where it's saved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the SQLite database is available in the `/data/data/your.applications.package/databases/database.db` path.

So, you could use that path; however, I suggest that you get the Database Path in the following way:

```
File dbFile = getDatabasePath("dbname");
String dbPath = dbFile.getPath();
```

Then, you can copy the database from this folder into the folder that you desire.
Copying the database to the `Downloads` could simulate the "download" of the SQLite database.

Comment: Well, your application is on the user's phone, correct? So is the SQLite database. So, it kind of is on the user's device, they just can't access it right away to send it to you.

Comment: Can you check my update? I think i'm making some mistakes cause nothing is happening

Comment: I don't see any problem with the code to be completely honest. I have to ask, have you checked if you have the necessary permissions (`android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`)

Comment: Yes yes I have this permission. but i don't have sd card. Does that make any difference?

Comment: Shouldn't be related to the SD Card, I'll check the copy function and let you know if there's something wrong. But there shouldn't be. Testing it out for myself and I'll be right back to you. Just a matter of some minutes

Comment: This is the path i gor from Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath();---> storage/emulated/0. I cannot locate that path on my device!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206008/discussion-between-nizar-and-rav).

Comment: The problem you have is with the Path to the Database, I updated my answer in order to fix your problem.